# mod_rewrite - rewrite all subdomains except "m" to something

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule for rewriting all subdomains to some URL, but I would like to edit it to rewrite all subdomains except subdomain "m".

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.myweb\.cz
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myweb.cz/adverts/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.myweb\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.myweb\.cz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myweb.cz/adverts/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative lookahead in your condition to avoid matching `m.`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!m\.)[^.]+)\.myweb\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myweb.cz/adverts/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```